# How to echo values from this array?

Tags: php, arrays

can someone help me to echo [file] value and [label] value from following array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [label] => 360p
            [type] => video/mp4
            [file] => /uploads/myVideo.mp4
            [res] => 360p
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [label] => 720p
            [type] => video/mp4
            [file] => /uploads/myVideo.mp4
            [res] => 720p
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [label] => 480p
            [type] => video/mp4
            [file] => /uploads/myVideo.mp4
            [res] => 480p
        )

)
```

Comment: What have you tried in order to resolve this yourself first?

Comment: it seems like an array of objects http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php

Comment: foreach($data as $results):
      echo '<span>'.$results['file'].'</span>';
      echo '<span>'.$results['label'].'</span>';
 endforeach;

Comment: You should have posted that in your question "at first light". ^ and to edit your question with what you tried http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43216819/edit @AbeliaZahfarina

Comment: sorry, im new in here.. can you edit my question? ^_^

Comment: Why can't you [edit] your own question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `foreach` to loop through all item and call in the array like:

```
foreach($yourArray as $item) {
    echo $item->label;
    echo $item->file;
}
```

Or you can be using `json_decode` to cast your object to the array.

```
$result = json_decode($data, true);
```

Comment: the results is  Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in D:\xampp\htdocs\13.php on line 31

Comment: @AbeliaZahfarina sorry, I don't see your data type is object. See my update answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can access elements inside a `stdClass` like this:

```
foreach ($test as $v) {
    echo $v->file;
    echo $v->label;
}
```